# Adding Extra method to interface

Tags: interface

I have a tricky question on interface. Please try to give me a solution for it.

Scenario:
I have written an interface with five methods. Also I have implemented more than 100 classes using this interface. Now, I need to add one more method to the interface. Consequently, I will need to define the same method in all classes. How can I avoid this???

Please reply...

Thanks,
Akif

Comment: Depends on the language being used.

Answer (score 25):

Could you avoid adding a method to the interface by instead creating a new interface which inherits from that first interface and then only changing the classes you need that new method on?  Hence, if `foo` didn't need the new method, leave it alone but if `bar` did, change it to the new interface.

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 has *default method* which you could add to an interface

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

All the subclasses which do not override this method will resort to the default implementation in the interface